# Django Retrieve id and name based on a ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have the following models :

```
class Projects(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)



class Packages(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    extension = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    gen_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Projects)
```

In my views, for the Homepage function, I'm trying to display the last package, AND the associated project.  I don't understand how to retrieve the 'project' field (FK) :

```
try:
    lastpackages = Packages.objects.reverse()[:1].get()
except Packages.DoesNotExist:
    lastpackages = None

projectid = lastpackages.select_related('project_id')
project = Projects.objects.get(id=lastpackages.project)

return render(request, 'homepage.html', {'lastpackages': lastpackages,
                                         'project': project})
```

In fact, I want to display the 'projectname' corresponding to the package retrieved by `reverse`.  But the lines projectid and project are not correct. I hope it's enough clear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say but your code is a bit messy. You don't need to look up the `Project` separately, django ORM does it for you:

```
package = Package.objects.order_by('-id')[0]
project = package.project
```

`package.project` would give you the project associated with the package, no need to query using `id`.

Some advises here:

1. You don't need to define `id`, django will do it for you.
2. Don't use plural form in your model name, django will do it for you.
3. In view it's usually good exercise to use [get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) to get the object, it saves your try except block.
4. `reverse()` should be used along with `order_by()` statement. In your case it's easier to just use `id` to find the last entry, because in django `id` is auto incremented.

Comment: Thank you for your advices !  I'll try to use  get_object_or_404 .      But `project= package.project` line returns `QuerySet object has no attribute project `

Comment: I don't really understand what's the purpose of `package = Package.objects.reverse()[:1].get()`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: With this line,  I want to display the last entry in Packages table.  My project is about packaging statistics.

Comment: You shouldn't depend on `reverse()` alone to determine what's the last result. See my updated answer.

Comment: I was thinking that `reverse` already did the good `order_by` on all the entries ...  That's not the same ??      And with this method, I got "Packages object not iterable",  I think because I use   "{% for %} {% empty% } {% endfor %}"  in my template.

Comment: Django queryset could have any order, so you need `order_by` to explicitly define the order. You've already answered your own question, for loop is going through a list of things, but you have only one object, you cannot expect loop to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
lastpackage = Packages.objects.reverse()[0]
project = lastpackage.project
```

Comment: With `Packages.objects.reverse()[0]` I got  "Packages object not iterable" (maybe due to  the 'for loop'  in template... ).   But even with the initial reverse line, I got   `QuerySet object has no attribute project` due to the project affectation ...

Comment: Your model should be ordered prior to use reverse(). You can also try `Packages.objects.latest('id')`. Since you try to get only one package it can not be iterated. Why do you need to use `for` loop?

Comment: Ok, it's working by removing the for loop,  but when using {% if packages != None %} , I can't display another message when pkg list is empty... so in this case,  "list index out of range"

Comment: EDIT : sorry, in fact the problem is  `packages = Packages.objects.order_by('-id')[0] `  when pkg table is empty.  I don't understand why it fails on 'try' .

Comment: If there are no packages at all your query should return 'list index out of range'. Use try-except and set `packages = None`  if the exception raised.

Comment: Ok, I changed the first 'try except' by removing 'DoesNotExists', and then I added a second 'try except' for the second line (project =).  That's more heavy, but it's working.  Thank you for part of the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to keep in mind is that `lastpackages` is a `Packages` object, not a Queryset, so this line is wrong:

```
projectid = lastpackages.select_related('project_id')
```

It should return `AttributeError: 'Packages' object has no attribute 'select_related'`

About what you're asking, once you have a `Packages` object, you can get the corresponding project id like this:

```
lastpackages.project.pk
```

And the full `Projects` object, if needed:

```
lastpackages.project
```